# xjc generated code references OverrideAnnotationOf annotation from sun internal package

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to generate Java classes from a set of XML schemas. The following binding file is used to handle mixed content in the schemas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
 xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
 xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
  <jaxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The code generation works fine but one of the generated classes has an @OverrideAnnotationOf from the com.sun.xml.internal.bind.annotation package. This package is included in rt.jar but the regular java compiler can't find it (and probably shouldn't find it because it is sun internal).

Is there a way to deal with the mixed content and not have the OverrideAnnotationOf from a sun internal package in my generated code?

Comment: I figured out that I can compile the generated classes with the -XDignore.symbol.file=true option (see http://andrew-haley.livejournal.com/) but then my application may not work on different JRE's

Comment: The problem is solved by moving to the XJC ant task. It also generates code with an OverrideAnnotationOf annotation but now it comes from the com.sun.xml.bind.annotation package that is included in jaxb-impl.jar.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 6 and up, oracle moved the JAXB implementation embedded within the JRE  to a different package to prevent potential collisions with the external [JAXB reference implementation](https://jaxb.java.net).

So the class `OverrideAnnotationOf` got moved from package `com.sun.xml.bind.annotation` to package `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.annotation`.

The embedded xjc, however, still generates java files that are annotated with `com.sun.xml.bind.annotation.OverrideAnnotationOf`(!)

Therefore, the JAXB implementation shipped with Java 7 will not understand its own output generated with `generateMixedExtensions="true"`. Even if you use the `-XDignore.symbol.file` option.